# Updating multiple columns of a csv based on a key using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a powershell script that downloads data from an API and exports it to a .csv file.  I would like to be able to run it on a regular basis, downloading only what has changed since the last API call and update the existing .csv file.

For example:

```
InitialData.csv
FormID,FormType,LastEditor,Status
F440,Permits,Bill,Opened
F443,Inspeciton,John,Opened
F446,Permits,Clare,Opened

Update.csv
FormID,FormType,LastEditor,Status
F440,Permits,Bill,Closed
F446,Permits,John,Opened
F449,Permits,Bill,Opened

Output.csv
FormID,FormType,LastEditor,Status
F440,Permits,Bill,Closed
F443,Inspeciton,John,Opened
F446,Permits,John,Opened
F449,Permits,Bill,Opened
```

As you can see 2 records were edited and one added as part of the update.

I'm sure this would be easier if I was working with a database server, but my options are limited to working with powershell and .csv files.

Comment: Please show your code attempts.

Comment: I would consider `Import-Csv` for reading the CSV files into objects. Then use `Group-Object` or `Compare-Object` to find differences/duplicates. Then use `Export-Csv` for outputting the objects into a CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the posted solution is that it doesn't account for changes in other columns of an existing `FormID` value. You can use [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.1) to pick the updated contents when there are duplicate `FormID` values.

```
$initial = Import-Csv InitialData.csv
$update = Import-Csv Update.csv
$initial+$update | Group-Object FormID |
    Foreach-Object {
        $_.Group[-1]
    } | Export-Csv Output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Explanation:**

`Group-Object` groups objects based on the provided property names (`FormID`). Each object with matching property values are grouped into a `GroupInfo` object. When piping those groups to `Foreach-Object`, `$_.Group` is a collection that contains those objects. `$_.Group[0]` will be the first object examined that contains a match. `$_.Group[1]` will be the second object that contains a match. The order is determined by the order of objects piped into `Group-Object`. A neat trick with PowerShell is the index `[-1]`, which is always the last object in a collection. So if a grouping produces only a `[0]` value or both a `[0]` and `[1]` value, we always want the last object `[-1]` because we check `$update` after `$initial`.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative.  I have tested the original method and it works perfectly with my test data.  Having said that, the live files will grow by about 140,000 rows a month and are 27 columns wide, so I'll try your method to see if it improves performance and report back.

Comment: I have merged the same two files using both methods.  Due to differences in the methods I had to sort the files by the same field before comparing them, but they matched perfectly.  However, @Buxmaniak method took 6:24 and @AdminOfThings method only took 3:20.  Thank you both for your efforts, but it looks like the `group-object` method is better for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
# What about this ...

$Local:InitalData_Content = Get-Content -Path (Join-Path -Path $PSScriptroot -ChildPath "InitialData.csv") | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ","
$Local:UpdateData_Content = Get-Content -Path (Join-Path -Path $PSScriptroot -ChildPath "Update.csv") | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ","
$Local:OutputData_List    = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList

# copy all items from $UpdateData_Content to $OutputData_List
$UpdateData_Content | ForEach-Object { [void]$OutputData_List.Add($PSItem) }

# get all items of $InitalData_Content whose FormID not exitits in  $UpdateData_Content and add them to $OutputData_List
$InitalData_Content | Where-Object { $PSItem.FormID -notin (@($UpdateData_Content.FormID)) } | ForEach-Object { [void]$OutputData_List.Add($PSItem) }

($OutputData_List | Sort-Object -Property "FormID" | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation) -replace '"' | Out-File -FilePath (Join-Path -Path $PSScriptroot -ChildPath "Output.csv") -Force
```

Comment: Thank you @Buxmaniak that worked.  I simplified it to the following as I was getting some errors regarding the path, but I'll give you the credit :)

Comment: Shame on me, I didn't know "Import-Csv" and "Export-Csv".  So we learned something from each other.  Perfect!  Thanks a lot @David T  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$InitalData_Content = Import-Csv -Path ./OriginalData.csv
$UpdateData_Content = Import-Csv -Path ./UpdatedData.csv
$OutputData_List    = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList

# copy all items from $UpdateData_Content to $OutputData_List
$UpdateData_Content | ForEach-Object { [void]$OutputData_List.Add($PSItem) }

# get all items of $InitalData_Content whose FormID not exitits in  $UpdateData_Content and add them to $OutputData_List
$InitalData_Content | Where-Object { $PSItem.FormID -notin (@($UpdateData_Content.FormID)) } | ForEach-Object { [void]$OutputData_List.Add($PSItem) }

$OutputData_List | Export-Csv ./Output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```